# Cinnamon Date/Time applet not using user timezone

Tags: time, cinnamon, time-zone

Cinnamon 4.0.9-1

System time is set UTC.

I've set the test user timezone to be my local timezone by using the command.

```
export TZ="US/Pacific"
```

Run the "date" command and it shows the local timezone time from the command line while logged into the test user.

System time/timezone still reporting UTC which is exactly what I want.

The calendar applet that shows the time only shows the system time.

Is it possible to allow this user to see their local timezone in the clock and how to do it?  I'm interested to know if I can do this via the command line or editing a config file that in the user home folder as these desktops will be managed from a configuration server.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue doing the following.

I had set in the test user /home/test/.bashrc which wasn't working.
TZ='{TIMEZONEPATH}'; export TZ

I moved the TZ line into the /home/test/.profile which worked.

For good measure I made sure the /etc/localtime was linked to the correct tz file.
I also created /etc/timezone and set the same timezone as localtime.